# N-body with Yampa FRP, haskell

Tags: haskell, frp, yampa

I am trying to make an n-body solver (a bunch of objects gravitationally attracted to each-other). The problem is that it looks like the gravity1 function does not feed back the return objects, resulting in linear motion of the objects:

The code looks like this:

```hs
    updateGame :: Game -> SF AppInput Game
    updateGame game = 
      proc input -> do
        ...
        objs        <- updateObjects' $ _foreground (Game._objects game) -< ()
    
        ...
    updateObjects' :: [Object] -> SF () [Object]
    updateObjects' objs =  parB . fmap (updateObject1 objs ) $ objs
    
    updateObject1 :: [Object] -> Object -> SF () Object
    updateObject1 objs0 obj0 =
      proc () -> do
        obj  <- gravity1 (objs0, obj0) -< ()
        returnA -< obj
    
    g = 6.673**(-11.0) :: Double
    
    gravity1 :: ([Object], Object) -> SF () (Object)    
    gravity1 (objs0, obj0) =
      proc () -> do
        let
          m0     =  _mass obj0               :: Double
          xform0 = (head . _transforms) obj0 :: M44 Double
          p0     = ( view (_w._xyz)) xform0  :: V3 Double
          
          ms     = foldr1 (+) $ fmap (_mass) objs0              :: Double
          xforms = fmap (head . _transforms) objs0              :: [M44 Double]
          ps     = foldr1 (^+^) $ fmap ( view (_w._xyz)) xforms :: V3 Double
    
          dir  = ps ^-^ p0                 :: V3 Double
          dist = norm dir                  :: Double
          f    = g * m0 * ms / dist**2.0   :: Double
          acc  = (f / ms) *^ (dir ^/ dist) :: V3 Double
          s    = 1000000000000000.0
          
        --vel <- ((_velocity obj0) ^+^) ^<< integral -< (s *^ acc)
        vel <- ((_velocity obj0) ^+^) ^<< integral -< (s *^ (DT.trace ("acc :" ++ show (s *^ acc)) $ acc))
    
        let mtx =
              mkTransformationMat
              rot
              tr
              where
                rot = (view _m33 xform0)
                tr  = vel + p0
          
        returnA -< obj0 { _transforms = [mtx]
                        , _velocity   = vel }
```

Running the code, there's the output I read in the console:

```
acc :V3 12105.49700148636 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 NaN NaN NaN
acc :V3 (-12105.49700148636) 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 12105.49700148636 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 NaN NaN NaN
acc :V3 (-12105.49700148636) 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 12105.49700148636 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 NaN NaN NaN
acc :V3 (-12105.49700148636) 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 12105.49700148636 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 NaN NaN NaN
acc :V3 (-12105.49700148636) 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 12105.49700148636 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 NaN NaN NaN
acc :V3 (-12105.49700148636) 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 12105.49700148636 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 NaN NaN NaN
acc :V3 (-12105.49700148636) 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 12105.49700148636 12105.49700148636 0.0
acc :V3 NaN NaN NaN
```

Basically the values are all the same (the NaN's are due to object computed against itself, which I should fix, but that's not the issue here), it looks like the gravity1 function does not feed back the return object, despite return value being:

```hs
    returnA -< obj0 { _transforms = [mtx]
                    , _velocity   = vel }
```

The result is the linear motion of the objects, since acc seems to be a constant.

My expectation here is that after`gravity1 :: ([Object], Object) -> SF () (Object)` has updated and returned the object, the `updateObjects' objs =  parB . fmap (updateObject1 objs ) $ objs` and `updateObject1 objs0 obj0 = ... returnA -< obj` should result in all objects being updated and next iteration cycle should feed the `gravity1 :: ([Object], Object) -> SF () (Object)` with an updated set of objects, so that the value of `acc` is different every frame...

Am I misunderstanding the logic of how things are supposed to work here?

Comment: Interesting. Please make this a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the type of `gravity1`:

```hs
gravity1 :: ([Object], Object) -> SF () (Object)
```

This is a function that, when provided with a list of `Object` and a particular `Object` will produce a signal function.  This signal function is a so-called *generator*, meaning that it can be provided with empty input and continually produce a stream of `Object` output.

Thus, in essence, `gravity1` as two different kinds of inputs:

- It has *static* input `([Object], Object)`, which it gets once and is forever unchanging, and
- It has *streaming* input `()` (which is basically equivalent to no streaming input).

With this in mind, it does make sense that, once supplied with its static arguments, `gravity1` will produce a constant stream of `Object` — after all, it is never receiving updated data about where any `Object`s are!

In order to make the output stream dynamically *react* to changes in the positions of the objects, those positions need to be streaming, not static.  In particular, the `[Object]` input should be streaming:

```hs
gravity1 :: Object -> SF [Object] Object
```

The other input argument, which specifies the starting position of the `Object` we care about, probably doesn't need to be streaming, but it does need to be dealt with carefully (it is only a *starting* position after all).

But if `gravity1` takes the positions of the `Object`s as a streaming argument, how will you run it from `updateObject`?  You will likely need to use some form of [delay](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Yampa-0.13.1/docs/FRP-Yampa-Delays.html), such as:

```hs
updateObjects :: [Object] -> SF () [Object]
updateObjects objs0 = proc () -> do
  rec objs  <- iPre objs0 -< objs'
      objs' <- parB (fmap gravity1 objs0) -< objs
  returnA -< objs'
```

Incidentally, this strategy of using delay (i.e., the `rec` keyword along with `iPre` or something similar) is exactly what you'll need to use in `gravity1` also to keep track of the current position of the particular object that you're calculating the gravity for.